# Webscraping Javascript enabled website using Selenium in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a dictionary, the dictionary website page is like this:

- there is a search box for typing words to look them up
- there is a button so that after typing the word you have to click it to see the results
- the problem is the website is designed using JavaScript, it means that when I click the Go button, the web-page URL does not change, just the content inside a `div` changes, `<div id="dict_entry">content of the entry for the given word goes here</div>`
- note that when clicking go button the search box content is posted to the server using post method by JavaScript.

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mydictionary.com/dictionary");
                var searchField = driver.FindElementById("search");
                var searchButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"search_submit\"]");
                searchField.SendKeys("writer");
                searchButton.Click();
                var result = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"dict_entry\"]").Text;
                File.WriteAllText("result.txt", result);



            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that when I navigate to `http://mydictionary.com/dictionary` the dictionary loads the default first entry which is the entry for word: `a`, and I am trying to get the entry for word: `writer` but my code gets the content of word `a` because it does not wait for the form to be submitted to the server and get its response before scraping the web-page. Since the web-page is a JavaScript driven one, how can I make sure that the response of my JavaScript form post has returned so that I will scrape it after getting the new JavaScript manipulated DOM?

In other words: how can I wait for the newly created DOM by JavaScript before webscraping?

Comment: Why not just reproduce the same XHR which produced when you click go button in a browser and submit the webform?

Comment: give me an example please

Comment: @acman123 You can use your browser to inspect website's activities when you click "Search" button in "Console" and "Network" Tabs. Then you could do scrapping better.

Comment: @acman123 Take a look at [XHR examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%23+xhr+post+application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded). Examine XHR which is logged when submit form in e. g. Chrome developer tools, network tab, you can find there parameters that should be sent. Please specify some example URL for further insight.

Comment: the website uses authentication, therefore I need the appropriate cookies, and only by using a web-browser I get those cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution which waits for the jquery to complete and it seems it is working:

```
while (true) // Handle timeout somewhere
    {
        var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        if (ajaxIsComplete)
            break;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2733

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use `Clear()` method first before `SendKeys()`

```
searchField.Clear();
searchField.SendKeys("writer");
```

Comment: Your response is completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly wait for the Web Element using the code below

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("id")));
```

and then get the result.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the item is already visible because all entries in a dictionary share the same css class and id names. When searching a word in a dictionary, only the content of those divs change not the id names or class names.